# ActiveMQ Artemis Security with OAuth2

Tags: activemq-artemis

Is there a way where we can configure OAuth2 in ActiveMQ Artemis. I found this material [Extending Artemis Security with OAuth2](https://medium.com/@joelicious/extending-artemis-security-with-oauth2-7fd9b3dffe3). Is there anything in the [ActiveMQ Artemis User Manual](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/) for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveMQ Artemis can integrate with [KeyCloak](https://www.keycloak.org/) (which implements OAuth2). There's an example referenced in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/examples.html#security-keycloak).